How to link the rotation angle of multiple bones to a single value?
How can I have the IK X rotation Max. Value for multiple bones link to one specified value for the IK X rotation Max. Value?
I’m thinking along the lines of having a bunch of cells in Excel link to one specified value.
Thanks for your help.

Check out more on drivers, this is what this is known as in Blender.

Hi @Jakemoyo, if I’m using a Copy Rotation constraint on bones 2 to 6, how can I have the maximum rotation limit of the bone being referenced, bone 1, be driven to only be 1/6 of the rotation of a controlling bone? Thank you.

I can't say exactly off the top of my head. But if you look in that documentation re: drivers you should see a part where you can script it with basic python and math operations. Like something like rotation_euler.x / 6 as the driver for bone 1.

Here's where that part is.
